# How can I iterate through a .text file, starting from the end using Windows Powershell?

Tags: powershell, loops, text

I want to go through a .txt/.log file line by line (with powershell). I have to start at the last line and make my way up to a specific line.
Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? This is really basic, here are just some hints: (https://ss64.com/ps/for.html), (https://ss64.com/ps/get-content.html), (https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/12/05/learn-simple-ways-to-handle-windows-powershell-arrays/)

Comment: In addition to @Paxz I would mention the order of an array. (https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/09/02/powertip-reverse-array-with-powershell/)

Comment: Note that both answers will only work for small-ish files. When processing large files reading the entire file into an array will quickly exhaust memory. Why do you think you need to read the file back to front in order to get to a specific line? What does that line look like? Can you provide more details about what you want to match, and what you need to do with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the file with Get-Content, reverse the array and iterate trough it:

```
$content = Get-Content -Path "C:\path\to\my\file.txt"
[array]::Reverse($content)

$content | foreach {

    $_ # Do something...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve this. Here is the basic iteration:

```
@'
Hello
Cruel 
World
'@ | Out-File demo-file.txt

$content = Get-Content demo-file.txt

for ($lineNumber = $content.Length-1; $lineNumber -ge 0; $lineNumber--) {
    "$content[$lineNumber]"
}
```